# Using three.js, how would you project a globe world to a map on the screen?

Tags: three.js, map-projections

I am curious about the limits of three.js. The following question is asked mainly as a challenge, not because I actually need the specific knowledge/code right away.

Say you have a game/simulation world model around a sphere geometry representing a planet, like the worlds of the game Populous. The resolution of polygons and textures is sufficient to look smooth when the globe fills the view of an ordinary camera. There are animated macroscopic objects on the surface.

The challenge is to project everything from the model to a global map projection on the screen in real time. The choice of projection is yours, but it must be seamless/continuous, and it must be possible for the user to rotate it, placing any point on the planet surface in the center of the screen. (It is not an option to maintain an alternative model of the world only for visualization.)

There are no limits on the number of cameras etc. allowed, but the performance must be expected to be "realtime", say two-figured FPS or more.

I don't expect ayn proof in the form of a running application (although that would be cool), but some explanation as to how it could be done.

My own initial idea is to place a lot of cameras, in fact one for every pixel in the map projection, around the globe, within a Group object that is attached to some kind of orbit controls (with rotation only), but I expect the number of object culling operations to become a huge performance issue. I am sure there must exist more elegant (and faster) solutions. :-)

Comment: If you need to reproject from sphere to map I guess you are doing it wrong. When you are placing objects on sphere you know their position on map (say, lat / lon) already so you could form flat map from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not just use a spherical camera-model (think a 360° camera) and virtually put it in the center of the sphere? So this camera would (if it were physically possible) be wrapped all around the sphere, looking toward the center from all directions.

This camera could be implemented in shaders (instead of the regular projection-matrix) and would produce an equirectangular image of the planet-surface (or in fact any other projection you want, like spherical mercator-projection).

As far as I can tell the vertex-shader can implement any projection you want and it doesn't need to represent a camera that is physically possible. It just needs to produce consistent clip-space coordinates for all vertices. Fragment-Shaders for lighting would still need to operate on the original coordinates, normals etc. but that should be achievable. So the vertex-shader would just need compute `(x,y,z) => (phi,theta,r)` and go on with that.

Occlusion-culling would need to be disabled, but iirc three.js doesn't do that anyway.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Hm, I realize that I need more basic knowledge about vertex shaders to understand this answer. I am considering accepting your answer, as it seems at first glance like a viable approach presented by someone who knows 3D graphics. Are you confident about this approach, or is it more of an educated guess? Would this perform in real-time? Have you done strange projections with vertex shaders before, or defined custom cameras using vertex shaders?

Comment: Well, there is one downside that the projection isn't really describing a view-volume transformation like a regular projection-matrix. This comes with one problem that there has to be a seam-line across the globe that will be represented by both the left and right edge of the map. Triangles across this line would then span the width of the whole map and need to be discarded first. But that's something that could probably be taken care of in some way. It's not something I actually wrote, but it should be possible without any performance-impact compared to regular rendering.